# Advanced JSDoc (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

**Primary problem: I need type extending any object structure with the concrete object structure.**

Default I tested in VS Code.

My solution proposal:

```
/** @template A @typedef {{[Ki in keyof A]:       A[Ki] } & {[k: string]:       {} } & A} Deep3 */
/** @template A @typedef {{[Ki in keyof A]: Deep3<A[Ki]>} & {[k: string]: Deep3<{}>} & A} Deep2 */
/** @template A @typedef {{[Ki in keyof A]: Deep2<A[Ki]>} & {[k: string]: Deep2<{}>} & A} Deep */

/** @type {Deep<{a: {b: number}}>} */
let x = {a: {b: 9, c: {d: 8}}};     // ERROR: Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ [k: string]: {}; }'
x.a.c.d = 9;    // OK
```

Problem resulting from my solution proposal:

```
/** @type {Number & {[k: string]: Number}} */
let a = 9;          // ERROR: Type '11' is not assignable to type '{ [k: string]: { x: number; }; }'
a.optional = 9;     // OK

/** @type {Number | {[k: string]: Number}} */
let b = 9;          // OK
b.optional = 9;     // ERROR: Property 'optional' does not exist on type 'number'
b = 4;
```

This problem is not exists here:

```
/** @type {Number & {optional?: Number}} */
let c = 9;          // OK
c.optional = 9;     // OK
```

In TypeScript is behavior equals.

Answer (score 0):

your code help me to found a way for my issue.
Not sure if we have same issue, but here my code.
Basically adding `Partial< code >` remove assignable alert for me ! :)

```js
/**@type  { Partial<{[Ki in keyof A]: A[Ki] }> } */
```

[image]